# Remove featured image in Post

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove the featured image in post and page, but keep it as thumbnail so that the site look good! My site is a wordpress based site.

Here's an example post of the site: http://www.tradingspotsilver.com/build-mt4-custom-ea-indicator-forex-free/

You could see that the featured image is on top of the post and occupy a lot of space. I've tried to look at the theme source but no luck.

Comment: you want thumbnail size image rather than this big one http://www.tradingspotsilver.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/strategyquant_ea_wizard_1-580x333.png?

Answer (score 1):

The link given in your question is a single post page, you look in to your theme's root folder and can find a file named `single.php`, in that file you may find something like this

```
// "custom_size" could be anything like "single_page_image"
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : the_post_thumbnail('custom_size');
```

This line of code is responsible for showing the big image. Just remove this line and your image will not show up. Also, you may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713924/how-do-i-resize-access-original-images-in-wordpress/13714606#13714606) for custom image sizing.

For page template, you may look for a file named `page.php` and look for the similar code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use timthumb for resizing:

with the code here: { https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/source/browse/trunk/timthumb.php }

create a file named timthumb.php in your theme folder, and at  the place of the featured image php script, type:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
              //the_post_thumbnail();
            $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
            <div class="img-hold"> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $url; ?>&w=219&h=125" width="219" height="125"  /></div>
            <p><?  } 
                echo $content;  
            ?></p>
```

---

change the value of height and width as per your wish at &w=, &h= and also width= , height=

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `the_post_thumbnail` code in the single.php and page.php or content.php.
this function use in [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) for show featured so just remove or comment it.

Answer (score 0):

check your single.php and content.php page to solve this problem its right there

if you dont require that code comment it / or modify it as you want. 
dont mess things go easy with it or otherwise you will end up getting error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i could not find any solution in single.php

Its simple although:

just comment:

from content.php  page

Answer (score 0):

This is for the Dazzle Theme
I found mine in "content-single.php and removed :

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'dazzling-featured', array( 'class' => 'thumbnail' )); ?>
```

Picture was gone from post.

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously varies depending on theme.

For theme **Freemium** you need to remove the following lines in *wp-content/themes/freemium/single.php*:

```
  <?php $freemium_feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); if($freemium_feat_image!="") { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $freemium_feat_image; ?>" alt="Banner" class="img-responsive img-responsive-freemium" />
                <?php } ?>
```