# Refresh original image data

Tags: wordpress, image, ftp

I am about to upload a large number of images to a Wordpress site.

I'll need to resize and replace them until the size is deemed to be the best one. I plan to make the first upload by FTP and then a plugin like [Media From FTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-from-ftp/).

Sequential uploads will be also be done by FTP. The problem is that this will not update the original image data in the database (for example the dimensions which will be different).

I've seen the plugin [Enable Media Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-media-replace/) regenerating original image information, but only for a specific image while I want to do this in batch. I've seen thumbnail regeneration plugins but I'm uncertain that they update the original image's data so I don't know if there's a way.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that questions asking for recommendations or opinions are discouraged: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam" Ref: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @FluffyKitten thanks for the clarification, at least I know why the question is downvoted. Still, I want to say that I've seen plugin suggestions very often within Stack Overflow for askers who were researching specific functionality, and my case is the same.

Comment: You will get some people who answer questions regardless of whether it is on topic, but bear in mind that it is discouraged and your question could get flagged for deletion as off-topic. You could try some Wordpress forums maybe, but I'm not really sure of any so I can't really advise you where to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, here's what I did :

1. Downloaded my images by FTP
2. Made my resize operations and re-uploaded my images using FTP
3. Installed [WPR Rebuild Meta Data plugin](https://github.com/WPRanger/wpr-rebuild-meta-data) to rebuild all the modified image meta data
4. Installed [Force Regenerate Thumbnails plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/) to regenerate thumbnails.

I give a more thorough description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713924/how-do-i-resize-access-original-images-in-wordpress#answer-45989295).